# Python Tkinter Treeview Shift-Up binding is one iteration behind input

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I want to be able to also use the `<Shift-Up>` keys to select through the items in the treeview. No errors are given but the selection is late with one element. In my code, I am intending for the selection to be the same as the focus, but the selection ends up being on element down the list.

My guess is that the default binding for Arrow-Up key is being run after my  binding.

I have searched for a virtual event to replace the `<Up>` in my binding - something that has a similar functionality to `<<TreeviewSelect>>` as opposed to `<ButtonPress-1>` - but with no luck.

Any idea how to synchronize the selection and focus when `<Shift-Up>` is pressed?

Note: the selectmode for the tree is set to none as in my main application I need the selection to be done slightly different than the default.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
class Treeview_Select:
    def __init__(self, tree):
        tree.bind('<Shift-Up>', self.ShiftUp, add='+')
    def ShiftUp(self, event):
        if event.widget.index(event.widget.focus()) is not '':
            print(event.widget.index(event.widget.focus()))
            event.widget.selection_set(event.widget.focus())
app = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(app)
v_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(app, orient='vertical', command=tree.yview)
tree.config(selectmode='none', yscrollcommand=v_scrollbar.set)
tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
v_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nes')
Treeview_Select(tree)
for i in range(14):
    tree.insert("", 'end', text=i)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***" the selection is late with one element"***: No, your `.selection_set(...` is to **early**. Read this relevant answer [Ttk Treeview: track keyboard selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49360860/7414759)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `tree.prev(item)` for this kind of action. If you want to implement a `<Shift-Down>`, use `tree.next(item)`.

```
def ShiftUp(self, event):
    if event.widget.index(event.widget.focus()) is not '':
        previous = event.widget.prev(event.widget.focus()) #use current focus to get previous one
        event.widget.selection_set(previous)
        event.widget.see(previous) #make sure the new selection is shown
```